# Binary calculation

Tags: binary

I need help to calculate Processor Affinity value

```
0 (0000)    Not allowed (that would mean use no processors)
1 (0001)    Use processor 1
2 (0010)    Use processor 2
3 (0011)    Use both processors 1 and 2
4 (0100)    Use processor 3
5 (0101)    Use both processors 1 and 3
6 (0110)    Use both processors 2 and 3
7 (0111)    Use processors 1,2 and 3
8 (1000)    Use processor 4
```

With 1, 2, 3 and result is 7. I wonder what formula is?

Comment: It cannot be 1,2 and 3 to result in 7, as 3 represents 1 and 2, so it should be 1,2,4 using binary OR which results in 0111 which is 7.

Comment: *With 1, 2, 3 and result is 7.* ??

Comment: "3" is a position in this context, which is represented by '0100' in binary, which is 4 in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a simple 4-digit [binary number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system).

A 1 at the right-most position means 1, a 1 at the second position from the right means 2, at the 3rd it means 4 and at the 4th position from right (i.e. the first digit from left) it means 8. The total value is simply the sum of all those positions.

The basic idea (in pseudo-code, because we can't format formulas correctly here is):

```
totalValue
for every digit at position i (counted from the right, starting with 0)
  totalValue = totalValue + 2^i*(digit at position i)
```

For example 3 (`0011`) the value is `0x2^3 + 0x2^2 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^0 = 0 + 0 + 2 + 1 = 3`

For example 4 (`0100`) the value is `0x2^3 + 1x2^2 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^0 = 0 + 4 + 0 + 0 = 4`

Comment: So how to calculate it for example: 3, 4?

Answer (score 0):

```
Processor_Affinity := Use_processor_1 + Use_processor_2 + Use_processor_3
```

Answer (score 0):

So 1010; interpret it as:

```
0 at 1st position as OFF
1 at 2nd position as ON
0 at 3rd position as OFF
1 at 4th position as ON
```